# superclass access check failed: class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws, java-17

I am getting the following error while using spring-ws-core.3.1.1. This was working fine except we have upgraded our platform and require us to use Java 17 (previous version was build on Java 11). Here is the code calling external service.

```
customerRequestType = buildCustomerRequest(customerModel);
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
JAXBElement < CreateCustomerRequestType > jaxb = objectFactory.createCreateCustomerReques(customerRequestType);
JAXBElement < CreateCustomerResponseType > responseJaxb = (JAXBElement < CreateCustomerResponseType > ) customWebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(jaxb);
CreateCustomerResponseType customerResponse = responseJaxb.getValue();
```

here is the Spring definition

```
<bean id="customWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientMessageFactory" />
    <property name="defaultUri" value="${vertex.service.create.customer.endpoint}" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="customerJaxbMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="customerJaxbMarshaller" />
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
            <property name="connectionTimeout" value="5000" />
            <property name="readTimeout" value="5000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

There is complex logic or anything, while calling the external endpoint, this is what I can see in the error log

```
    "thrown": {
    "localizedMessage": "superclass access check failed: class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl (in unnamed module @0x7045bf72) cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom to unnamed module @0x7045bf72",
    "extendedStackTrace": [
        {
            "line": 106,
            "class": "com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl",
            "file": "SOAPPartImpl.java",
            "method": "<init>"
        },
        {
            "line": 70,
            "class": "com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl",
            "file": "SOAPPart1_1Impl.java",
            "method": "<init>"
        },
        {
            "line": 96,
            "class": "com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl",
            "file": "Message1_1Impl.java",
            "method": "getSOAPPart"
        },
        {
            "line": 138,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage",
            "file": "SaajSoapMessage.java",
            "method": "getEnvelope"
        },
        {
            "line": 38,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage",
            "file": "AbstractSoapMessage.java",
            "method": "getSoapBody"
        },
        {
            "line": 56,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage",
            "file": "AbstractSoapMessage.java",
            "method": "getPayloadResult"
        },
        {
            "line": 79,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils",
            "file": "MarshallingUtils.java",
            "method": "marshal"
        },
        {
            "line": 402,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$2",
            "file": "WebServiceTemplate.java",
            "method": "doWithMessage"
        },
        {
            "line": 572,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate",
            "file": "WebServiceTemplate.java",
            "method": "doSendAndReceive"
        },
        {
            "line": 542,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate",
            "file": "WebServiceTemplate.java",
            "method": "sendAndReceive"
        },
        {
            "line": 394,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate",
            "file": "WebServiceTemplate.java",
            "method": "marshalSendAndReceive"
        },
        {
            "line": 388,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate",
            "file": "WebServiceTemplate.java",
            "method": "marshalSendAndReceive"
        },
        {
            "line": 378,
            "class": "org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate",
            "file": "WebServiceTemplate.java",
            "method": "marshalSendAndReceive"
        }
```

Since its a managed cloud environment, I have limited options while compiling the code or passing any additional parameter to JVM. Anyone have any idea what might be the RCA and what can be the corrective action to fix this issue?

**Edit**
I am able to get some details on the error, this is what the original error look like

```
Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.toString()
```

This is thrown by `MarshallingUtils` class in Spring-WS. Here is the method

```
 public static void marshal(Marshaller marshaller, Object graph, WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {
        if (marshaller instanceof MimeMarshaller && message instanceof MimeMessage) {
            MimeMarshaller mimeMarshaller = (MimeMarshaller)marshaller;
            MimeMessageContainer container = new MimeMessageContainer((MimeMessage)message);
            mimeMarshaller.marshal(graph, message.getPayloadResult(), container);
        } else {
            marshaller.marshal(graph, message.getPayloadResult());
        }

    }

 MimeMessageContainer container = new MimeMessageContainer((MimeMessage)message)
```

above line seems to create the issue when trying ti build the SOAP request

Comment: What does java.xml look like? Is the XML parser for SOAP in a javax or Jakarta system and what level. What are all your cloud software supplied too.

Comment: Need to check as I have limited visibility on the config and setup. trying to get something from cloud team but not much success

Comment: E.g. is the spring app using Jakarta and the server using javax, you would need to find a suitable XML parser if you require to supply the parser and work in the correct proprietary name javax or Jakarta.

Comment: Agree but seems some changes from Java 11 to 17 since the same code and dependencies were working as expected.

Comment: Sorry I slightly misread the error, it thinks the java.xml is a module, take a look for syntax errors "in your code" at the lines in the files the error specifies that may be causing the java.xml to be read. Bad comment block? Unterminated line?  ...  There is also potential you have not made your class extended from the required SOAP class for the service or implemented a required interface for soap , or imported statement. Check around INIT method in your code.

Comment: SOSP if it isn't a simple message is considered to require "large" web service classes or interfaces.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant I think the point on the response/request having some Unterminated line seems a valid point..let me check

Comment: java.xml is a bit deceitful in the error message , it is referring to the java package used in javax.xml.ws.Endpoint , that "probably" corresponds to the bean configuration ${vertex.service.create.customer.endpoint} , it probably does not evaluate if that is a special startup environment variable. You should show your complete code to know if it is not simply a config import issue or a missing .jar

Comment: To narrow it your source code does not have the import statement for com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.*;  for Xerces xml parser perhaps your saaj-impl does not have this or Xerces xml parser, go find a variant of saaj-impl that has it

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-saaj/issues/165        https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/issues/93         Dependent your server  https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/622570?language=en_US

Comment: Artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles.saaj-impl
Group org.apache.servicemix.bundles
Version 1.5.1_1
Last update 03. February 2019
Tags: impl file bundle osgi this wraps saaj

License not specified
Dependencies amount 4
Dependencies stax-ex, stax-api, activation, org.apache.servicemix.specs.saaj-api-1.3,

 https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl

org.apache.servicemix.bundles.saaj-impl-1.5.1_1.jar  ? needs any  javax or jakarta or transparent note SE core has xml and node processing classes.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of a missing dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```